# Retrieve multiple rows from MySQL database using Java Hibernate and store it in a variable

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, hql

Until now I've tried the following code:

```java
UserDate u; 
SessionFactory sf=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
Session session=sf.openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
Query queryResult = session.createQuery("from UserDate");
List<UserDate> l=queryResult.list();
for(int i=0; i<l.size(); i++) {   
    System.out.println(u.getClient_Name()+"     "+u.getAppointementDate()+"     "+u.getAssessment_year()+"     "+u.getUnder_section());
}
```

Now I need to store all the rows of the MySQL table in a single variable string. UserDate is the mapped class. Furthermore, I need to use the variable in which all the rows will be stored, or else help me find a way to store the output of the for loop used.

```java
package p1;@Table(name = "user_dates")@Entity
public class UserDate {

    @Id@GeneratedValue
    private int dateId;
    private String appointementDate;
    private String reminderDate;
    private String summary;
    private String Client_Name;
    private String assessment_year;
    private int mailStatus;

    public int getMailStatus() {
        return mailStatus;
    }

    public void setMailStatus(int mailStatus) {
        this.mailStatus = mailStatus;
    }

    public void setAssessment_year(String assessment_year) {
        this.assessment_year = assessment_year;
    }

    public String getAssessment_year() {
        return assessment_year;
    }

    private String under_section;@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Employee.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)@JoinColumn(name = "empID", referencedColumnName = "empID")
    private Employee employee;

    public int getDateId() {
        return dateId;
    }

    public void setDateId(int dateId) {
        this.dateId = dateId;
    }

    public String getAppointementDate() {
        return appointementDate;
    }

    public void setAppointementDate(String appointementDate) {
        this.appointementDate = appointementDate;
    }

    public String getReminderDate() {
        return reminderDate;
    }

    public void setReminderDate(String reminderDate) {
        this.reminderDate = reminderDate;
    }

    public String getSummary() {
        return summary;
    }

    public void setSummary(String summary) {
        this.summary = summary;
    }

    public String getClient_Name() {
        return Client_Name;
    }

    public void setClient_Name(String client_Name) {
        Client_Name = client_Name;
    }

    public Employee getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }

    public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }

    public String getUnder_section() {
        return under_section;
    }

    public void setUnder_section(String under_section) {
        this.under_section = under_section;
    }
}
```